# MSBUILD Configuration: Copy output to staging area

Tags: msbuild

Ok, I am not the best at MSBUILD. Actually, I don't know anything. I need some help configuring my solution file to tell MSbuild to copy the compiled output into a staging area. The solution has about 35 projects. All I need is around 5 of them the to be copied to the staging folder in release mode. Please assume I know nothing...

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could create a Target that looks like this:

```
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" DependsOnTargets="YourBuildTargets">
    <CreateItem Include="YourSolutionPath\bin\$(Configuration)\*.*">
      <Output ItemName="YourProjectOutputFiles" TaskParameter="Include"></Output>
    </CreateItem>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(YourProjectOutputFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DestinationFolder)"></Copy>
  </Target>
```

This will create a target called `CopyFiles` which depends on the completion of `YourBuildTargets` (You can put multiple dependencies in there, separated with semi colons). It describes an Item which includes all of the files (*.*) in the project directory. Then it runs the `Copy` command, and copies the files described by the item to the destination folder. If you have lots of projects all being build by 1 MSBuild script, you would have a `CreateItem` node for each project to index the files, and a corresponding `Copy` node to perform the copy.

Or if you just want to do this for each project separately, just put this block inside each .csproj file.

Now just include the `CopyFiles` target in the list of targets that gets build by your script.

Comment: Does this go into the solution file?

How do I set "YourProjectOutputFiles"?

Comment: No. The .csproj files are the MSBuild scripts. Put this in each of the .csproj files that you want the copy to run on.

Comment: "YourProjectOutputFiles" is just the name of the output of the item, you don't need to change it.

Comment: If you are just doing this by putting the code in each .csproj file, you should probably change the include property on the CreateItem node to just something like "$(TargetDir)\*.*", and you will need to change the DestinationFolder attribute on the Copy node to point to where ever you want the files to go.

Comment: If you are using visual studio you could also do all of this just by right clicking and going to "Properties" on each project and going to the "Build Events" tab and adding a command to the "Post-build event command line". This just accepts standard commands, and if you hit the "Edit" button there are some simple macros you can insert to help you get the directories right. I didn't realise you were doing this from visual studio, I thought you wanted MSBuild scripts.